# gganimate invalid times argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gganimate

I am trying to make a convergence plot, but I am getting the error

> Error in rep(seq_len(nrow(polygon)), splits + 1) :
> invalid 'times' argument

How do I get around this error.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

set.seed(42)
n <- 10
mat <- matrix(runif(n*25, 0, 1), ncol = 25)
mat_mean <- apply(mat, 1, mean)
mat_sd <- apply(mat, 1, sd)

df_unif <- tibble(i = seq_along(mat_mean), 
        mu = mat_mean, 
        sd = mat_sd, 
        cum_mean = cumsum(mat_mean) / seq_along(mat_mean), 
        cum_sd = cumsum(mat_sd) / seq_along(mat_mean))

a1 <- df_unif %>% head(1) %>% mutate(facet = 1)
a2 <- df_unif %>% head(2) %>% mutate(facet = 2)
a3 <- df_unif %>% head(3) %>% mutate(facet = 3)
a4 <- df_unif %>% head(4) %>% mutate(facet = 4)
a5 <- df_unif %>% head(5) %>% mutate(facet = 5)
a6 <- df_unif %>% head(6) %>% mutate(facet = 6)
a7 <- df_unif %>% head(7) %>% mutate(facet = 7)
a8 <- df_unif %>% head(8) %>% mutate(facet = 8)
a9 <- df_unif %>% head(9) %>% mutate(facet = 9)
a10 <- df_unif %>% head(10) %>% mutate(facet = 10)

df_facet <- bind_rows(
  a1, 
  a2,
  a3,
  a4,
  a5,
  a6,
  a7,
  a8,
  a9,
  a10
  )

anim <- df_facet %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = i, y = cum_mean))+
  geom_line() +
  ggplot2::ylim(c(0,1)) +
  ggplot2::xlim(c(0,n)) + 
  gganimate::transition_states(facet)

anim_save(filename = "plots/gif1/anim.gif", animation=anim)
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine using `gganimate` `1.0.8`.

Comment: Same error for me with `gganimate` 1.0.8. I'm on Windows, @stefan do you use linux or mac?

Comment: Apart from that, you can replace your `a1` to `a10` + `bind_rows` by `mutate(facet = 1:10)`

Comment: @bretauv Yep. Running on a Mac.

Comment: @bretauv I am on linux. Maybe it is an OS problem. Also thanks for the `mutate(facet)` tip

Comment: turn out the following works
`anim <- df_unif %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = i, y = cum_mean))+
  geom_line() +
  ggplot2::ylim(c(0,1)) +
  ggplot2::xlim(c(0,n)) + 
  gganimate::transition_reveal(i)`